# Getting an error while configuring spring security.xml The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, spring-security

I am getting an error on the line number 6 "The markup in the document  following the root element must be well-formed".I tried to find out why but no idea.

```
 <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/xxxx**" access="xxxx" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/xxx**" access="xxx,xxx" />
</http>
    <authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="xxx" password="xxx" authorities="xxxxx" />
    <user name="xxxx" password="xxxx" authorities="xxxxx" />
    <user name="xxxx" password="xxxxx" authorities="xxxx" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your xml code doesn't contains any beans tag.

Try to add your code between the beans tags like

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

------ Your Code -------

<beans:beans>
```